Is "me's" a word?
I was writing out song lyrics and the guy pronounces "me is" (as in "ignoring me is bad enough") as "me's". Is this a real spelling or just sloppy pronunciation? I do like the idea of this but cannot find it anywhere.

In songs it's not unusual to fit the lyrics to the music, so compressing "me is" to "me's" might be a requirement to make the lyrics flow with the music.

Sure, you can have a clitic form of is or has at the end of a subject ending in me. It is oral English mostly.

Why didn't you just ignore me? Ignoring me's fine. (Interview with
Ridley Scott, Den of Geek)
Just being me's bad enough. (Movie: FAQs, 2005)
Commercial use's always allowed and crediting me's always optional. (Terms of Use)
Nothing you're telling me's going to change my offer. (Lincoln Lawyer, Script)
If what you're telling me's true, then that's all the more reason why you have to help me. (Novel: Rain. Gallagher, Stephen)
Mrs. Wallace: Yeah, and, Bethie, that's why Luis will go back to her. He's done that before. So killing me's not going to do any good, you know, not with you snagging Luis. (TV: Passions, 2003)
Shooting me's a lot better than what's coming for all of us. (Movie: ZK Elephant's Graveyard, 2015)

CGEL (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language) on the topic of clitic forms of is and has says "these clitics place fewer requirements on what may serve as their host, allowing hosts that are not subject pronouns," and goes on to give an example with a clause as subject.

That they’re wet’s obvious enough.

So, though rare in writing, it seems that it's common enough in spoken English (and written records of spoken English) to be acceptable in song lyrics.

Used in dialogue by writers. So, writing is as writing does. Probably found a lot in Faulkner, for example.
